# How to load Omnipay to Codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried adding `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` on index.php in root folder but that  didn't work I got `Fatal error: Class 'Omnipay' not found`. Also adding `use Omnipay\Omnipay;` causing this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT'

Filename: Common/AbstractGateway.php

Line Number: 208
```

I have used composer to install omnipay plugin.
I am not sure how to properly load [omnipay](https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay) in codeigniter controller?

Comment: Did you place it in the libraries folder or your app? What CI version are you using?

Comment: You can include the class file in your code. Just map it to the correct folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omnipay is loaded and working fine.

> Message: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT'

You don't have the curl PHP extension enabled on your server. Ask your host to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

Please put API folder in /application/third_party folder after that please create codeigniter in /application/library folder as named `Omnipay_call.php` or as per your requirements

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
require_once(APPPATH. 'third_party/Omnipay/vendor/autoload.php');

class Omnipay_call extends Omnipay {

     /**
     *
     * @param type $rules 
     */
    public function __construct($rules = array()) {
        list($use, $key,......,$__n) = array();
        $gateway = Omnipay::create($use);
        $gateway->setApiKey($key);
    }
```

}

in controller

```
$this->load->library("omnipay_call", $params = array());
```

Comment: I followed your instruction, but I was served with this error: Class 'Omnipay' not found in <b>/application/libraries/omnipay_call.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />

Comment: `Omnipay` class not loaded correctly, try this path `require_once(APPPATH. 'third_party/Omnipay/vendor/autoload.php');` i missed `third_party` in old answer, update now and following correct path there `Omnipay` library saved